# Como redirecionar para uma tela específica ao clicar numa notificação com o app completamente fechado usando firebase messaging > v9.0

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Estou usando a versão 9.0 do firebase messaging e desejo redirecionar o usuário para uma tela específica ao receber e clicar em uma notificação quando o app estiver fechado.

Atualmente consigo redirecionar com o app aberto ou minimizado, mas não compreendi como realizar essa ação quando a aplicação não estiver aberta.

```dart
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  Model model = Model();
  id = "sasassa";
  Get.offNamed("$SCREEN_ROUTE",arguments: model);
  Storage storage = Storage();
  storage.setReceivedNotification(true);
  print("teste notificação recebida");

}

FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message){
    if (message != null){
      Model model = Model();
      id = "sasassa";
      Get.offNamed("$SCREEN_ROUTE",arguments: model);
    }
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    print("a");
    storage.setReceivedNotification(true);
    Model model = Model();
    id = "sasassa";
    Get.offNamed("$SCREEN_ROUTE",arguments: model);
    //storage.setUserChallenged("60f23d0803c1fd000a03c36e");
    //showMyDialog(corpo: message);
    //Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/events');
  });


  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
    print("b");
    storage.setReceivedNotification(true);
    print("teste b $message");
    String? corpo = message.notification?.body;
    String? titulo = message.notification?.title;
    String? image = message.notification?.android?.imageUrl;
    //showMyDialog(titulo: titulo,corpo: corpo);

    print("$corpo $titulo $image");

  });
```

Tentei usar shared preference no backgroundHandler, mas dessa maneira ocorrerá o redirecionamento mesmo sem o usuário clicar na notificação.

Alguém teria instruções de como realizar o redirecionamento com o app fechado a partir do click numa notificiação específica?

PS: Sei que preciso mandar os dados no corpo da notificação, só quero entender como fazer o flutter capturar o click com o app fechado na versão 9.0 ou superior.

Comment: Procure sobre _Deep Link_ no Android e iOS, com isso você conseguirá fazer o que deseja.

Comment: Matheus Ribeiro, agradeço seu comentário.
Eu já usei dynamic links para realizar abertura do app fechado a partir do click em links.

Minha dúvida mais precisamente seria sobre a captura do clique na notificação com o app fechado, conseguindo identificar esse evento eu consigo fazer o que quero, realmente o Deep Link tem relação direta pra realização essa ação em notificações?

Answer (score 0):

Até agora a pouco eu estava fazendo um aplicativo "Notifications Demo" para entender os conceitos da notificação e do Firebase Cloud Messaging. E consegui realizar todas as funções que eu queria.

Eu tenho um método chamado `initialize` para a classe `FireBaseCloudMessagingService` que é chamado no `initState()` da inicialização do aplicativo

```dart
class _AppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeFirebaseMessaging();
    super.initState();
  }

  initializeFirebaseMessaging() async {
    await Provider.of<FirebaseMessagingService>(
      context,
      listen: false,
    ).initialize();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}
```

Vou mandar a classe inteira pra te ajudar, ele tem algumas falhas, mas consegui fazer o que *eu* queria pelo menos:

```dart
class FirebaseMessagingService {
  final NotificationService notificationService;

  FirebaseMessagingService({required this.notificationService});

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    print("initializating Firebase");
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
      alert: true,
    );
    getDeviceFirebaseToken();
    _onMessage();
    _onMessageOpenedApp();
  }

  Future<void> sendNotification(String to, CustomNotification message) async {
    print("-- sendNotification");
    String url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "key=a chave do seu servidor Firebase Cloud Messaging",
    };

    Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      "to": to,
      "notification": {
        "title": message.title,
        "body": message.body,
      },
      "data": {
        "type": "Mensagem",
        "id": message.id,
        "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
      },
    };

    final http.Response response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      body: json.encode(body),
      encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"),
      headers: headers,
    );

    print("-- status code: ${response.statusCode}");
    print("-- body: ${response.body}");
  }

  Future<void> subscribeToTopic(String topic) async {
    print("-- subscribeToTopic($topic)");
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic(topic);
  }

  Future<String> getDeviceFirebaseToken() async {
    print("-- getDeviceToken");
    final String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    return token ?? "";
  }

  // AQUI ESTÁ O QUE VOCÊ ESTÁ PRECISANDO! \/ \/ \/ \/ \/
  _onMessageOpenedApp() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((_goToPageAfterMessage));
  }

  _goToPageAfterMessage(RemoteMessage message) {
    final String route = message.data["route"] ?? "";

    if (route.isNotEmpty) {
      Routes.navigatorKey?.currentState?.pushNamed(route);
    }
  }

  // AQUI ESTÁ O QUE VOCÊ ESTÁ PRECISANDO! /\ /\ /\ /\ /\

  _onMessage() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;

      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        notificationService.showLocalNotification(CustomNotification(
          id: android.hashCode,
          title: notification.title!,
          body: notification.body!,
          payload: message.data['route'] ?? "",
        ));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Aquela classe Routes da parte que é a sua resposta, eu que criei, nela eu fiz o seguinte:

```dart
class Routes {
  static Map<String, Widget Function(BuildContext)> list =
      <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    '/login': (_) => const LoginPage(),
    '/options': (_) => const NotificationOptions(),
    '/notification': (_) => const NotificationPage(),
    '/messenger': (_) => const MessagingPage(),
  };

  static String initial = '/login';

  static GlobalKey<NavigatorState>? navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
}
```

Você vai colocar o navigatorKey no MaterialApp do seu aplicativo, arquivo main.dart